# Using Make and GCC from Docker to compile local source tree

Tags: docker, gcc, gnu-make

So I am experimenting with Docker and I am contemplating a possibility of compiling a source tree on my local machine, using `gcc` & `make` and some more dependent libraries from a Docker container running locally.

Is it even possible? If yes, how do I go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible. There's an official `gcc` image that does exactly that.
There's a couple of example Dockerfiles on their [dockerhub page](https://hub.docker.com/_/gcc), that will help you get started:

```
FROM gcc:4.9
COPY . /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
RUN gcc -o myapp main.c
CMD ["./myapp"]
```

Or, without building an image:

```
$ docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp gcc:4.9 gcc -o myapp myapp.c
```

Comment: what this does is - it creates a temporary (--rm) docker container, mounts the local folder as a volume (-v) compiles and exits, leaving only the resulting binary left.